# Sorting in product page using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have made a product page and has added filter functionality using search bar and add to cart functionality also i want to sort the product in asec and dsec order onclick on low to high and high to low using redux
But i am not able to sort it can anyone please help .

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import useData from './useAPI'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { add } from './Redux/slice'
import { sort } from './Redux/slice'


export const Home = () => {
    const [data,setData]=useState([])
    const dataObj=useData()
   
    function setSearch(){
        setData(data)
        
    }
    const dispatch=useDispatch();

   const handleClick=(product)=>{
            dispatch(add(product))
            }

    const sorting=(product)=>{
      dispatch(sort(product))
    }

  return (
    <>
    <div className="navbar p-4 h-24">
    <input type="text" placeholder='Search Your data....' className='my-2 h-1/2 w-96 border-2 text-center text-l border-slate-400 rounded-l-xl'   
    value={data} onChange={(e)=>setData(e.target.value)}/>

    <button onClick={setSearch} className='bg-slate-300 text-xl h-1/2 w-24 rounded-r-xl border-2 border-slate-200 font-extrabold '>Search</button>
    </div>
    <div>
    <select>Sort
    <option onClick={sorting()}>Low to High</option>
    <option>High to Low</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div className="product flex flex-wrap justify-center w-screen h-full cursor-pointer">

    {
        dataObj 
        .filter((val) => {
                if(data == ""){
                  return val;
                }else if(val.title.toLowerCase().includes(data.toLowerCase())){
                  return val;
                }
              })
              .map(product=>(
                <div className='productCard h-84 bg-slate-50 w-72 flex justify-center flex-wrap rounded m-12 px-2 py-2 hover:scale-95 ' key={product.id}>
            <img src={product.image} alt="product" className='h-32 w-40'/>
                <div className='items-center w-full h-1/2 my-2 text-m'>
                <h2 className=' text-sm font-semibold py-1 '>{product.title}</h2>
                <h3 className='text-green-900 font-semibold py-1'>₹{product.price}</h3>
                <p className='text-blue-950 font-semibold py-1'>{product.rating.rate}⭐</p>
                <button 
                className='bg-purple-800 text-white font-semibold text-m px-2 py-2  rounded-xl hover:bg-blue-800'
                onClick={()=>handleClick(product)} >ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
                </div>
    
            ))
            
        }
    

    
    </div>
    
    </>
  )
}

========================================================================================================

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const CartSlice=createSlice({
    
   
    name:'cart',
    initialState:[],
   reducers:{
        add(state,action){
            state.push(action.payload)
            
           


        },
        remove(state,action){
            return state.filter((item)=>item.id!==action.payload)
            

        },
        sort(state){
            return state.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
                var nameA = a.price,
                  nameB = b.price
               var res=nameA-nameB
              return res
              })
        }

    }
})

export const{add, remove, sort}=CartSlice.actions

export default CartSlice.reducer
```

Please review my code above and provide me the solutions

Answer (score 0):

First sorting option should be:

```
<option onClick={sorting}>Low to High</option>
```

then update sorting() to :

```
 const sorting = (event) => {
    const sortingOrder = event.target.value;
    const sortedData = [...dataObj].sort((a, b) => {
      return sortingOrder === 'lowToHigh' ? a.price - b.price : b.price - a.price;
    });
    setData(sortedData);
  };
```

and remove sort() from reducer as you don't need it.

The Home screen will be :

```
import React, { useState ,    useEffect(() => {
    if (dataObj) {
        setData(dataObj)
    }
}, [dataObj])} from 'react';
import useData from './useAPI';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { add } from './Redux/slice';

export const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const dataObj = useData();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
useEffect(() => {
    if (dataObj) {
        setData(dataObj)
    }
}, [dataObj])

  const sorting = (event) => {
    const sortingOrder = event.target.value;
    const sortedData = [...dataObj].sort((a, b) => {
      return sortingOrder === 'lowToHigh' ? a.price - b.price : b.price - a.price;
    });
    setData(sortedData);
  };


  return (
    <>
  
      <div>
        <select onChange={sorting}>
          <option value="lowToHigh">Low to High</option>
          <option value="highToLow">High to Low</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div className="product flex flex-wrap justify-center w-screen h-full cursor-pointer">
        {/* Use the sorted 'data' state to map and display the products */}
        {data
          .filter((val) => {
            if (data === "") {
              return val;
            } else if (val.title.toLowerCase().includes(data.toLowerCase())) {
              return val;
            }
          })
          .map((product) => (
            <div
              className="productCard h-84 bg-slate-50 w-72 flex justify-center flex-wrap rounded m-12 px-2 py-2 hover:scale-95"
              key={product.id}
            >
              <img src={product.image} alt="product" className="h-32 w-40" />
              <div className="items-center w-full h-1/2 my-2 text-m">
                <h2 className="text-sm font-semibold py-1">{product.title}</h2>
                <h3 className="text-green-900 font-semibold py-1">₹{product.price}</h3>
                <p className="text-blue-950 font-semibold py-1">{product.rating.rate}⭐</p>
                <button
                  className="bg-purple-800 text-white font-semibold text-m px-2 py-2  rounded-xl hover:bg-blue-800"
                  onClick={() => handleClick(product)}
                >
                  ADD TO CART
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: But it will not display the output in the product page after sorting

Comment: The data state has the sorted data. Use it rather than dataObj.

Comment: u mean to say this?                                                                                              
      sortedData 
        .filter((val) => {
                if(data == ""){
                  return val;
                }else if(val.title.toLowerCase().includes(data.toLowerCase())){
                  return val;
                }
              })
             .map(product=>(
                <div className='productCard h-84 bg-slate-50 w-72 flex justify-center flex-wrap rounded m-12 px-2 py-2 hover:scale-95 ' key={product.id}>

Comment: @TusharKumar I have edited the code. Rerun the code and provide me the feedback.

Comment: getting this after implementing the above code                                                        
 data.filter is not a function
TypeError: data.filter is not a function

Comment: because the sorted data is overwriting the input data tried by creating a new state variable but showing error for filter fnc

Comment: @ Muhammad Jawad Mansoor the logic is working but the new issue is the products are only displaying if we select low to high or high to low else the page is blank

Comment: Edited. Check and give me feedback

Comment: getting error: Uncaught TypeError: data.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: @TusharKumar tell me the purpose of val.title.toLowerCase().includes(data.toLowerCase())

Comment: it will fliter out the products having the word which we enter in the search bar

Comment: its working fine as per the filter and sort that u provided thanks for the help

Comment: I am facing issue that is remove the item from the cart if i am add the same product twice on clicking remove its deleting both of them at once .

Comment: Please find the code below:-import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const CartSlice=createSlice({
    
   
    name:'cart',
    initialState:[],
   reducers:{
        add(state,action){
            state.push(action.payload)
            
           


        },
        remove(state,action){
            return state.filter((item)=>item.id!==action.payload)
            

        },
        

    }
})

export const{add,remove}=CartSlice.actions

export default CartSlice.reducer